# ContourPlot - how to show linear values on log plot and how to expand the PlotRange for linear plot

Tags: plotting, legending, plot-themes

I have been struggling with this problem for long and I finally decided to post it. How do you change the range of contour plot or decide what contours to show? Also when your contour is in the log scale, how do you show the actual linear scale values, say the actual value of the contour is 0.1 and the contour shows -2.3. How do I make it show 0.1

Code

```
Π[Q_, α_, d_, 
  t_, β0_, η0_] := -((1. β0^(-((1 - d)/t) - (-1 + d +
             t)/t) Gamma[
       2 + (-1 + d)/
         t] ((t η0 PolyLog[(-1 + d)/t, -E^η0])/(-1 + d + 
           t) - PolyLog[(-1 + d + t)/t, -E^η0]))/(Q Gamma[(-1 + 
          d + t)/t] PolyLog[(-1 + d)/t, -E^η0]));

η[α_, d_, t_, β_, nd_] := 
  Quiet[Chop[
      FindRoot[
       2*-((2^-d π^(-d/2) α^-d β^(-(d/t))
   Gamma[d/t] PolyLog[d/t, -E^η])/(t Gamma[d/2])) == 
        nd, {η, 1000000}]][[1]][[2]]]; 
q := 1.6*10^-19; 
me := 9.1*10^-31; 
h := 6.63*10^-34;  
kb := 1.38*10^-23; 

ContourPlot[Π[q, h/(2 π)*vf*10^-2, 2, 1, 1/(
  kb*300), η[h/(2 π)*vf*10^-2, 2, 1, 1/(kb*300), 
   10^16]]/Π[q, h/(2 π)/(2 meff*me)^0.5, 2, 2, 1/(
  kb*300), η[h/(2 π)/(2 meff*me)^0.5, 2, 2, 1/(kb*300), 
   10^16]], {vf, 10^5, 10^9}, {meff, 0.01, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 ContourLabels -> All, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 15}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(v\), \(F\)]\) (cm/s)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \(eff\)]\)/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(m\), \
\(e\)]\)"}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", "Log"}]
```

[image]

We get this as the output. Now I basically have a few questions which I would like to be addressed:

1. Even when I want to stay in the log scale of my desired quantity, how should I make the contour values appear in linear scale i.e. when they are less than 1, I just don't want to see negative values.
2. When I plot this in linear scale, the range of values is so big that it doesn't show up in the co tour plot perfectly and there are a lot of white spaces on the plot. How should I make all the values appear on the plot even in the linear plot. You can see below that a lot of the values are in the purple region, I wan to get contours there as well (atleast a few). This is what I get in linear plot:
   [image]
3. How can I make the plot look better? As in, how can I make the contour lines more visible and some important contour values (such as 1) more prominent.
4. When I export the plot, by right clicking and saving as pdf, it doesn't save the legend/color bar. What should I do to save that in the same pdf?

Comment: The code doesn't run because of missing constants. If you have a super simple example that illustrates your problem that would be helpful. But at least it has to be possible to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry I just realized that, I'll add the constants.

Comment: @C.E. I edited the code, does it run now?

Comment: It's just a white square for me. You can try it by restarting your kernel and copying your code from here into a new notebook.

Comment: @C.E. It should work now, there was one silly error. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: yep, it works now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110491/discussion-between-indeterminate-and-c-e).