# Custom Contourlabel to show linear values on log plot

Tags: plotting

How can we use ContourLabels to show linear values of a function on the contour plot while the plot itself is in log scale?

Comment: Please provide a concrete example and specify what contour values that you want labeled.

Comment: Here is a question I posted earlier: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225684/contourplot-how-to-show-linear-values-on-log-plot-and-how-to-expand-the-plotra

Comment: does the option `ContourLabels -> (Text[N@Exp@#3, {#1, #2}] &)` give the desired result?

Comment: @kglr Thanks it worked, what are N, #1,#2 and #3?

Comment: @kglr Also how do I keep just two significant digits?